# Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push': undefined CordovaError

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cocoapods

When I try to build ios platform, I got below error.

I have tried this , but it does not work.https://www.bountysource.com/issues/40076372-failed-to-install-phonegap-plugin-push-undefined-error-version-should-contain-only-numbers-and-dots

Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for ios
Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push': undefined
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!\': \u001b[31m[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.\u001b[39m (CLAide::Help)\n\n\u001b[4mUsage:\u001b[24m\n\n    $ \u001b[32mpod\u001b[39m \u001b[32mCOMMAND\u001b[39m\n\n      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.\n\n\u001b[4mCommands:\u001b[24m\n\n    \u001b[32m+ cache\u001b[39m      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache\n    \u001b[32m+ env\u001b[39m        Display pod environment\n    \u001b[32m+ init\u001b[39m       Generate a Podfile for the current directory\n    \u001b[32m+ install\u001b[39m    Install project dependencies according to versions from a\n                 Podfile.lock\n    \u001b[32m+ ipc\u001b[39m        Inter-process communication\n    \u001b[32m+ lib\u001b[39m        Develop pods\n    \u001b[32m+ list\u001b[39m       List pods\n    \u001b[32m+ outdated\u001b[39m   Show outdated project dependencies\n    \u001b[32m+ repo\u001b[39m       Manage spec-repositories\n    \u001b[32m+ setup\u001b[39m      Setup the CocoaPods environment\n    \u001b[32m+ spec\u001b[39m       Manage pod specs\n    \u001b[32m+ update\u001b[39m     Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock\n\n\u001b[4mOptions:\u001b[24m\n\n    \u001b[34m--silent\u001b[39m     Show nothing\n    \u001b[34m--version\u001b[39m    Show the version of the tool\n    \u001b[34m--verbose\u001b[39m    Show more debugging information\n    \u001b[34m--no-ansi\u001b[39m    Show

Answer (score 1):

try running pod install or pod update inside platforms/ios